# X Quartz opening on new blank desktop on Mac

Tags: xquartz

I'm having a problem where if I run anything that uses xquartz, the GUI opens on a new black 'desktop' that doesn't have the dock, any icons or the top bar. I'm not sure why, and, for my uses, I need the programs to run on one of my regular desktop screens.

Earlier this year, I was trying to set this computer up to allow XForwarding to a remote computer, so I may have changed something that is causing this to happen, but I thought I had gone through and reset my ssh_config file and sshd_config file in case this is causing it to happen by reseting things to be commented out.

I can't think of anything else or what I might be able to do to stop this from happening (before trying to set up ssh, this was not an issue that I rememeber but I am not absolutely certain that it is what is causing the problem). Any ideas?

Thank you!

Bethany

Computer Specs:
Mac Pro 2017, OS: Mohave 10.14.6 (18G6032)

Comment: Perhaps you have set Quartz to Full Screen? See https://grammarofdev.blogspot.com/2018/01/exit-xquartz-full-screen-mode-macos.html

Comment: That was it, thank you. The menu bar at the top was not appearing on the full screen so I couldn't find a way to change it or see the application preferences. I had to use a fullscreen exit shortcut that I, admittedly, did not know (cmd+opt+A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have set XQuartz to Full Screen.

[image]

(picture from https://grammarofdev.blogspot.com/2018/01/exit-xquartz-full-screen-mode-macos.html)